# Getting text color from Silverlight RichTextBox

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox

I have a problem with the getting the RichTextBox`s text color. There is a method about it but i was fail with it. help me to use this method or is there any way to do this.
Here is the method

```
run.Foreground(DependencyProperty)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the answer of my question

```
((System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush)(run.Foreground)).Color.ToString()
```

with above code i can get the color of the text in hex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what that method is supposed to do, but in XAML you would use:

```
<RichTextBox Name="MyBox" Text="Some text" Foreground="Red" />
```

or you could bind it to a Brush property:

```
<RichTextBox Name="MyBox" Text="Some text" Foreground="{Binding myColor}" />
```

If you're trying to set it from code behind:

```
Brush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Red);
MyBox.Foreground = myBrush;
```